# Magento 2 - Plugin to run only when function is called from specific module

Tags: magento2, module, plugin

Is there any way that I can specify that a Plugin X only runs when the class is called from Module Y? 
So that if same function is called from other modules the Plugin is not called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you're probably better off using Dependency Injection to configure Module Y to use a Module Y-specific version of the class.

See devdocs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html#parameter-configuration-inheritance

> Any descendant can override the parameters configured for its supertype; that is, the parent class or interface:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="urlBuilder" xsi:type="object">Magento\Core\Model\Url</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Context">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="urlBuilder" xsi:type="object">Magento\Backend\Model\Url</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> In the preceding example, Magento\Backend\Block\Context is a descendant of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context.
>
> The first entry configures all instances of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context as well as its children to pass in Magento\Core\Model\Url as $urlBuilder in their constructors.
>
> The second entry overrides this and configures all instances of Magento\Backend\Block\Context to use Magento\Backend\Model\Url as the $urlBuilder instead.

So, if you make a modified implementation of Class, like `MyClass extends Class`, you can use DI to pass MyClass to specific classes in Module Y in place of Class.

```
<type name="Module/Y/Model/ExampleClass">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="something" xsi:type="object">Module/Z/Model/MyClass</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: hi @Ryan, can you elaborate it please, still not cleared. I have used the same plugin class in multiple modules.